# Font identification: On or off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

We're starting to get quite a number of "What's this font?" questions, and I'm curious, do we as a community think they should hold, or should we just get rid of them?

Comment: I don't think finding fonts was the purpose (or related to the purpose) of this site, and beyond that, the Q&A format doesn't serve the "Find this font" question. I think we need to call these off-topic at some point.

Comment: It strikes me as ridiculously lazy. Google font finder and you get 10. "Find this font for me." is EXACTLY like saying "Tie my shoe." - I find the question degrading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discussion of typography definitely seems on-topic.

Being lazy and asking people to figure out a font name for them? Well, I guess it's still related. But there are very dedicated sites out there for that already (typophile and myfonts being the main ones).

I'd put it up there with "what's the keyboard shortcut for doing this in Photoshop?" Certainly a GD related question, but hardly a question that I'd consider high quality and generating a lot of interest.

Comment: The problem is that if you are looking for font related questions they are all drowning in a sea of "what font is this?" questions right now. Maybe one year ago there weren't so many of these questions, but they are clearly getting out of control. Also I don't think they will help anyone except the OP because a user would have to go through all the questions to see if any of them is the one they are looking for... this in turn leads to more "What font is this?" questions. Could be a serious problem.

Comment: I would tend to agree. The 'what font is this' question has ruined typophile as well. We should probably avoid those questions.

Answer (score 4):

I think these can be on-topic -- so long as

1. they can provide an actual screenshot of the font (important)
2. there aren't too many, to the point that they dominate the site
3. these questions are a soft on-ramp for onboarding new members of the community

Some related discussion at

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/

Comment: 2 is less of an issue if people add it to their blocked tags...  right?  Or from a macro level, is it bad for newcomers to come to the site and see a disproportionate number of a specific type of question?

Comment: I saw [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74645/display-tag-excerpt-when-asking-a-question) about displaying tag excerpts on mouse-over.  Has there been any thought to raising the visibility of the excerpts?  In particular, many font-id questions are answered with http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ - which could be viewed in an excerpt directly from the question screen.  Many may not be aware of the mouseover trick.

Answer (score 3):

I think they are on-topic, fonts are within the core of graphic design. Like the "How do I...?" questions, we just need to figure out the best yet still easy way to manage them.

At minimum, we just need to be sure to tag them properly when they come in so that people who want to ignore them are able to easily. Also, If no one has done it yet, we should put in the tag wiki for the font-related tags information on what makes a successful query along with a list of the websites people have been using to identify fonts.

Comment: I've made an initial suggestion for the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they lack usefullness for other users as the questions lack searchabillity. A similair case came up recently on a the movie-site. "what movie is this" kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are totally on topic but only useful if they are not so easily found.
I'm getting all my rep through font identification, it's a bit too easy :-)

Just a thought but could we request people to type the leads given by Whatthefont or Identifont before answering the question? It makes sure they did the work, saves us some time and if there are no leads well it's a tough question and might attract more expert attention.

Comment: Hey @curious, you should have just gotten an email from me inviting you to a pre-screening session hosted by Stack Exchange. We’re trying to nail down a date before Friday, so if you are interested, could you let me know what times might work best for you?

Answer (score 0):

### I propose that we handle all future font identification requests like this:

We enjoy answering your design questions, we really do. However, we're no more capable than you are of finding the name of a font. Rather than being an intellectual question that we can answer for you, it's merely a chore.

However, in good faith, I've searched a (kinda close) match to your font for you: **[Vox Wide SemiBold from Canada Type Vox](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/vox/wide-semibold/)**

It might not be the perfect match, but if you want a more precise match, you may need to do some manual searching.

Please see:

- [How can I automatically determine fonts used in an image or PDF?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-i-automatically-determine-fonts-used-in-an-image-or-pdf).
- [How to manually identify a font when the automatic services fail?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/how-to-manually-identify-a-font-when-the-automatic-services-fail/4117#4117)

---

As a final note, remember, as some good logos use private or modified fonts, it may not be possible to find an exact match, no matter what you do.